# When power removed from LED circuit LED stays on

Tags: dc, dc-dc-converter, electrical

I have a 12v DC input that I am stepping down to 2v with 610 ohm resistor. When power is removed the light is staying on for a period of time and slowly dims.

Would the resistor be acting like a battery?

Any ideas if not the resistor?

Thanks

EDIT:
My circuit is a resistor wired to the positive arm of the LED and the negative wire off of the negative arm. I am connecting it to a car battery in this case. When I take the leads off the battery the light stays on and dims over time

Comment: We definitively need a circuit to answer your question. Or a thousands words of description, but a picture is worth... [sic]. Oh, and please [edit] your question, don't place additional information in some comments.

Answer (score 4):

> I have a 12 V DC input that I am stepping down to 2 V with 610 ohm resistor. When power is removed the light is staying on for a period of time and slowly dims.

I suspect that you mean when you switch off the **mains** power that the LED fades out.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdNJ7E.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. An old-fashioned power supply driving an LED.*

How it works:

- SW1 switches the power on and off.
- XFMR1 is a transformer and steps the voltage down from mains to the low voltage required - probably about 9 V AC in your case.
- BR1 is a bridge rectifier consisting of four diodes. No matter what the polarity of the input voltage on the ~ ~ terminals the voltage is "rectified" and current always comes out on the + terminal. The bridge rectifier will output pulses of current at the peaks of the alternating voltage.
- C1 is the smoothing capacitor which stores some charge between pulses from BR1.
- R1 limits the current to the LED to a safe value.
- D1, the LED, will have a certain "forward voltage", V<sub>f</sub>, at the current set by R1.

> Would the resistor be acting like a battery?

Definitely not. The fading effect is caused by the charge stored in C1 slowly bleeding out through R1 - D1.

Comment: Hmm my circuit is a resistor wired to the positive arm of the LED and the negative wire off of the negative arm and I am connecting it to a car battery in this case.  When I take the leads off the battery the light stays on and dims over time.

Comment: @markblue777 - Is that a "bare" LED? Or some kind of packaged "LED flashlight-type of device"? Please can you edit the question and add a photo or two showing the battery, wiring and the LED you are using? Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, those details and the details of the LED still haven't been edited into to your question.

Comment: Yeah because I was asleep.